# OpenGL lighting data for mesh - wastage

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting

I am developing a voxel engine similar to Minecraft, and am currently implementing basic lighting.

Ideally I would only need to store a lighting value for each block face (4 vertices), and the lighting value would be 4 bytes (RGBA).

At the moment, I am storing **3 floats for each vertex**.

Is there any way to only store and send to the shader the lighting data for each face, rather than each vertex?

And what is the best way to use an 4-byte integer? (In particular how to send to and use with GLSL). I've just used floats at the moment for testing, but would like to stop this memory wastage.

Comment: What do you mean by "lighting value" ? Normal ?

Comment: @Raki No, I mean the color that I multiply the original color of the face by to produce a lighting effect. Normals are not needed for this very simple lighting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a color for each vertex. Instead you can use uniform variables, uniform variables change between draw calls, so for example you can change the value when the material of the block changes.

Lets say you have blocks with red color and other blocks with blue color. You can do the separate draw calls by material like the following pseudo-code:

```
for each blocks with the same material
Material->UseProgram();
SetUniform3f ( location, Material->Color ) // Change the color 
DrawBlocks();
```

You can do it for each block but it is recommended to reduce state changes (program and uniforms) as much as possible.

Comment: Yeah but blocks with the same material will have different light values. And I render the blocks in chunks of 16x16 blocks, not individually.

Comment: @Brett what do you mean by light values? aren't you calculating light values on the fly? Light contribution mostly depends on the normal of the face using dot product.

Comment: lighting is precalculated based on a blocks exposure to the sun etc. then is given a light value. So each block face needs to have an independent light value which will be applied in the shader. No lighting calculations are done on the fly.

Comment: @Brett this info should have been added to the question from the beginning. You can store your light calculations in a compressed texture and lock up the values in your shaders.

Comment: Would an array of lighting values supplied to the shader as a uniform also work?

Comment: @Brett This will probably be worse than vertex streams because you need to update them each frame. I still recommend researching lightmaps (compressed).